# WildFly JBOSS Server Reverse Proxy

Tags: java, jboss, reverse-proxy, struts-1, wildfly-9

From last few Days we are facing some problem because of Firefox 93(latest version) protects against Insecure Downloads and due to this
Mozilla Firefox block insecure HTTP downloads on a secure HTTPS page,
so we can not download our report which was based on HTTP(without SSL) from our Production Site which is based on SSL Certified HTTPS

Here is I have shown how our report is generated from our Production site

1. whereas the user sending the request to fetch or downloading the report that time one request goes to the report Server via     Java Code and then the report server gives a response for report downloading or fetching a reports
   sample response URL  Report Server:  http//report.abc.com/mycertificate.doc
   so whenever we request a downloading a report at that time we get security-related warning from the Mozilla browser   while downloading the report

We try some tackle points as follows:

1. we were trying to make the report server SSL enable but  did not work for us because our report server is based on windows server 2003 so all supports from this windows server its almost not good enough for making SSL enable.

2)Reverse Proxy: we also used the concept of reverse proxy in our project which was deployed on JBoss (Wildfly version 9) for that we did configure some code in the standalone.xml file which follows:

Here is the some configuration changes which was we made but no luck for this:

```
     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <location name="/myservices/services" handler="myproxy"/>
            </host>
        </server>
       
   <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            <reverse-proxy name="myproxy">
               <host name="http://www.example.com" instance-id="myRoute" outbound-socket-binding="https-remote"/>
            </reverse-proxy>
        </handlers>
    </subsystem>


<outbound-socket-binding name="https-remote">
        <remote-destination host="http://www.example.com" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
```

above code snippet I have made changes to the JBoss standalone configuration file but did not  get help out from this configuration setting so, What I am looking for is a reverse proxy in Wildfly 9 to handle insecure HTTP downloads on a secure HTTPS page

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks